# Как правильно вычислить срок годности?

Tags: pascalabc.net

программирую на PascalABC.Подскажите в чем ошибка:
есть Дата производства,срок годности,и сама дата до какого числа годен продукт.
Мы вводим дни срока годности и программа высчитывает до какой даты годен продукт.
При маленьких числах примерно до 350 она работает нормально.Но если  ввести  больше то уже идет с погрешностью (месяц,или несколько дней).
Алгоритм таков:
 Дата производства+срок годности;если число дня больше месяца то он день минусуется на месяц
 и прибавляется  к +1 к месяцу;
если месяц больше 12 то он минусуется на 12 и +1 к году
также есть проверки  сколько  дней в каждом месяце.
Пример ошибки:дата производства:7.2.17,срок годности 500 дней
Ответ выдает:18.6.2018
Хотя правильный:22.6.2018
Спасибо за внимание!

```
  Program goden1;
 type mass=array [1..3] of integer;
 var dataPr:mass; k,dt:byte;//k-число дней в месяце
     data:mass;             //dt- для case
     srok:mass;
     goden:mass;

 BEGIN
 //дата производства
  dataPr[1]:=7;
  dataPr[2]:=2;
  dataPr[3]:=2017;
 //дата настоящая
  data[1]:=29;
  data[2]:=10;
  data[3]:=2018;
 //дата Годности
  goden[1]:=dataPr[1];
  goden[2]:=dataPr[2];
  goden[3]:=dataPr[3];

  writeln('Дата производства:',dataPr[1],'.',dataPr[2],'.',dataPr[3]);
  writeln('Дата настоящая:',data[1],'.',data[2],'.',data[3]);

  writeln('Введите срок годности.');
  writeln('Если вы хотите ввести день ,то нажмите: 1.');
  readln(dt);
  //Блок case
  case dt of
  1:Begin
     writeln('Введите дни.');
     readln(srok[1]);
     if goden[2] in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] then k:=31 //проверка на кол-во дней в месяце
     else if goden[2] in [4,6,9,11] then k:=30
     else if goden[2]=2 then 
     begin
      if (goden[3] mod 4 = 0) and //проверка на високосность
         (goden[3] mod 100 <>0) or
         (goden[3] mod 400 = 0) then k:=29
      else k:=28;
     end; 

     goden[1]:=dataPr[1]+srok[1];
     if goden[1]>k then
      while goden[1]>k do
       begin
        goden[1]:=goden[1]-k;
        goden[2]:=goden[2]+1;
        if goden[2] in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] then k:=31 //снова проверка,что-бы после goden[1]:=goden[1]-k; переходил на следующий месяц
        else if goden[2] in [4,6,9,11] then k:=30 
        else if goden[2]=2 then 
         begin
          if (goden[3] mod 4 = 0) and //снова проверка на високосность
           (goden[3] mod 100 <>0) or
           (goden[3] mod 400 = 0) then k:=29
          else k:=28;
     end;
       end;

     if goden[2]>12 then
      while goden[2]>12 do //переход на следующий год
       begin
        goden[2]:=goden[2]-12;
        goden[3]:=goden[3]+1;
       end;
    writeln('Продукт годен до:',goden[1],'.',goden[2],'.',goden[3]);
    end 
    else writeln('Введите 1');   
    end;    
    END.
```

Comment: Вы бы для начала определили, в какой именно момент возникает ошибка. 1 день прибавляет правильно? А 30? А 100?

Comment: Непонял ваше 2 предложение

Comment: Ну смотрите. Если, к примеру, до 31 декабря даты прибавляются правильно, а потом - нет, то ошибку надо искать где-то в коде перехода на следующий год. Вот я и предлагаю определить, до какой даты оно считает правильно, а где начинает ошибаться.

Comment: нашел где начинается ошибки: начиная с 393(с февраля) идет разница в месяцах

Comment: Еще в феврале 2018 февраль до 29 хотя он до 28

Comment: А, ну логично. В цикле перед проверками `if goden[2] ...` добавьте вывод `writeln(goden[2])`. Надеюсь, сразу поймете, в чем проблема. :)